# RewriteRule not working at server level?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I wanted to forbid some robots from doing certain things to my websites and decided to add a `RewriteRule` for that purpose.

The rule works when put in one of my `<VirtualHost *:80>` *tag* and looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule . - [F,L]
```

However, I wanted to apply that to all my websites instead of just one of them.

So with the newest version of Apache2 settings, I decided to put that code in the `security.conf` file. This file is defined under `/etc/apache2/conf-available/...` (and yes, I have a softlink from the `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/...` directory.)

However, if the definition is only in the `conf-available/security.conf` files, it somehow gets ignored.

From the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html), it says that these `Rewrite*` commands all work at server level!

Any idea of what I would be missing?

Comment: Aside: the pattern `.` matches a single character, so the `RewriteRule` won't match requests for the document root. Change this to `^` or `.*` to match everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `RewriteOptions Inherit` to each virtual server.

Reference:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions

Comment: Argh! I see that there is a new `InheritDownBefore` but I only have 2.4.6 and that one requires 2.4.8. Darn. I was hoping that it could be done without having to edit each virtual server... Too bad. I'll have to wait for the new version of Apache then.